# JQuery Colorbox $close.html(settings.close).show is not a function Error

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have included colorbox css and js files into my application. I have a link like that:

```
<a href="/changePassword.html" class="cboxElement" title="Change Password">Change Password</a>
```

and my js like that:

```
$(".cboxElement").colorbox();
```

However I get that error:

```
$close.html(settings.close).show is not a function
[Break On This Error] $close.html(settings.close).show();
```

Full code of method from colorbox plugin:

```
trigger(event_open, settings.onOpen);
$groupControls.add($title).hide();
$close.html(settings.close).show()// error happens here;
```

When I debug it with Firebug element of settings is like that:

```
h NaN

href "/pages/changePassword.html"

rel "nofollow"

title "Change Password"

w NaN
```

I use ColorBox v1.3.17.2

**PS:** Do I miss anything i.e. giving width - height? I want to load content from another page within may page.

Comment: How about showing us the unminified code or at least link to a readable version?

Comment: I took it from unminified code. I will organize it again

Comment: @alex I have edited my code and explained error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was loading HTML with a colorbox link externally. When I called the colorbox function at the callback of the load function, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't ever put the `cboxElement` class on things. That is used internally by colorbox to keep track of elements in your document. When you get errors like you are describing, it's usually from not using an `iframe` when use of an `iframe` would be required.